# how to add a file contents to a variable in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm not very experienced so please know I'm trying as hard as I can. How do I add the file's first contents (eg. 65) to a new entered number, then overwrite the file to save it?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Here is my programming:

```
henry = 0
emily = 0
george = 0
points = 0

file = open('nfc.txt','r+')
for line in file: 
    print(line)

if input("Who would you like to give points to? ") == "henry":
    points = int(input("How many points would you like to give to Henry? "))
    henry = henry + points
    print("Henry now has",henry, "points")
    points = 0
    file.write(str(henry)+" ")
    file.write(str(emily)+" ")
    file.write(str(george)+" ")
    file.close()

else:
    print("That name is not valid")
```

Comment: I believe you are opening the file read only. Take a look at the docs for open. Also take a look at pdb and experiment with debugging. I would put in some prints to see what's happening.

Comment: exactly what is not working, when I copy your code I can get nfc.txt to show `2 0 0` if I for the input give henry and 2. Your code will however only do something for `henry`, so it won't work for emily or george, but I believe you can figure out why on your own having come this far. Happy bug hunting.

Comment: Are you trying to alter the value in the file?  Please show the contents of `nfc.txt` then show what you expect to change.

Comment: Just an advice. Do not try to build a full program until you are able to to simple things. So 1/ define what data should lie in your file and what format you want to use (assuming text here since your current code write text data) 2/ Write code that writes the data in the file 3/ Write code that reads data from the file. When those 3 points are ok, put everything together and ask a more precise question if you are stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working when 'nfc.txt' exists in the directory. If the file is not there then use 'w+'. Mind it, if the file already exists then it will overwrite the existing one. Here is the link for more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm. Also, think about the comment made by ahed87. 
I hope, it will help. 
p.s: new edit to improve the answer

Comment: so open the file in w+ instead of write, and it will overwrite the contents of the previous nfc.txt file? @Toothless

Comment: Yes, quoting from the link I provided: w+ Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.

Comment: and @Toothless one more thing: how do i add the contents from the first number of the file to a variable? for instance: nfc=7 0 0, points=8, how do i add the file to 'points' to make 15 saved in the file?

Comment: Three suggestions that can help you: (a) Use data structure like dictionary to bind the name with value. That will help to ease  the programming task. (b)  Before reading the file, find out if file already exists or not. If it exists then use (r+). If not then create new(w+) one with initial value 0 for each person/name. You can use try/except statement for that. (c)To update the values, you have to first see what is inside the file. Read file--> ask for user input --> modify --> Write back to file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming I understood your question this should do it. it opens the file and gets the values before appending them with user input and writes them to the file. I have commented it in case you get lost I hope this helps.

```
file = open('nfc.txt', 'r+') ### opens file
f = file.read() ### reads file and assigns it to variable f
f = f.splitlines() ### slits file into list at any neline "\n"
scores = {} ### creates dictionary to store data


for line in f:
    line = line.replace(':', '') ### replaces colons with nothing
    line = line.split() ### splits name from score
    scores[line[0]] = int(line[1]) ###appends dictionary so name is key and score is values

name = input("Who would you like to give points to?").lower() ### user input
if name in scores.keys(): ### checks to see if input is a dict key
    point = int(input(
            "How many points would you like to give to {}?".format(name))) ### formats name into next input question
    scores[name] += point ### adds value to current score
    scores['total'] += point ### adds value to change total

    file.seek(0) ### sets position in file to start
    file.truncate() ### deletes all data in current file
    for key in list(scores.keys()): ### gets all keys from dict to ittereate
        file.write("{}: {}\n".format(key, str(scores[key]))) ### writes info to file with \n for new person
    file.close() ### closes file IMPORTANT

else:
    print("That name is not valid")
```

I do hope you don't mind having to scroll for the comments I know it is not very pythonic

Answer (score 0):

## Now it works

You have to use 'w' to write in a file

```
henry = 0
emily = 0
george = 0
points = 0

file = open('nfc.txt', 'w+')
for line in file:
    print(line)

if input("Who would you like to give points to? ") == "henry":
    points = int(input("How many points would you like to give to Henry? "))
    henry = henry + points
    print("Henry now has", henry, "points")
    points = 0
    file.write(str(henry) + " ")
    file.write(str(emily) + " ")
    file.write(str(george) + " ")
    file.close()

else:
    print("That name is not valid")
```

[image]

and in the file you got this

[image]